# How to loop through a dictionary in Julia?

Tags: loops, dictionary, julia

I want to loop through and print the (key, value) pairs of a dictionary in Julia. How can I do this?

I see how to [initalize a dictionary in Julia here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086594/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-in-julia), but I want to loop through it as well.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The solution is relatively simple:

```
x = Dict("a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "c"=>"C")

for (key, value) in x
    print(key); print(value)
end

# Output: cCbBaA
```

Check out [the Julia docs for Base.Dict](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.Dict) to learn more about functions you can apply to a Dictionary in Julia!

Answer (score 8):

you can also use this solution:

```
x = Dict("a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "c"=>"C")

for item in x
    print(item.first)
    print(" : ")
    println(item.second)
end

# output: 
#   c : C
#   b : B
#   a : A
```